# How to use helm-occur to search the whole word?

Tags: helm, search, syntax

For example, I got the following lines:

```
1. abc
2. abc def
3. abc_def
4. _abc
5. abc_
```

and I want to search only the word `abc`, so only the 1 and 2 lines matches, I googled a while, it says `\babc\b` would work, but it doesn't work for me, and I found that `\_<abc\_>` works.

But I want to make it work with helm-occur, such as when I use the regular `helm-occur` (I bound it to `Ctrl-s`), it should work as default `helm-occur`, but if I called it with a prefix argument (Ctrl-u), it will search the whole word instead of string on top of the `helm-occur`.

Is there anyone knowing how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, I found the solution from [this page](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/issues/2027), not directly modify `helm-occur` but it is useful.

```
(defun helm-occur-insert-symbol-regexp ()
    (interactive)
    (helm-set-pattern (concat "\\_<" helm-input "\\_>")))
(define-key helm-moccur-map (kbd "<right>") 'helm-occur-insert-symbol-regexp)
```

Use `<right>` key to search the whole in helm-occur session.
Better solutions are welcome.